# View memory distribution in java

Tags: java, performance

I am working on a Java application. I have assigned Xms=3gb and Xmx =4gb. I want to check that how much memory is assigned to young generation and old generation and survivor space. I have not explicitly defined the -XX:NewRatio or -XX:NewSize. I am using jdk 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jmap.html) command line tool:

jmap -heap <process id>

Answer (score 1):

[JVisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html):

The JConsole graphical user interface is a monitoring tool that complies to the Java Management Extensions (JMX) specification. JConsole uses the extensive instrumentation of the Java Virtual Machine (Java VM) to provide information about the performance and resource consumption of applications running on the Java platform.